# Missing 1 required positional argument (object created and dictionary initialized)

Tags: python, dictionary

I see this question has been asked before in different variations, but I feel as though I have implemented the feedback I have seen in those threads (mainly making sure the object is created as I have done in the second last night, and making sure the dictionary is initiated, which I feel I have done in the third line) and I am still receiving the error. Any advice would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

```
class Groceries:

def __init__(self, grocery_list):
    self.grocery_list = {}

def add_item(self, item):
    item = input("name: ")
    purchased = input(False)
    self.grocery_list[item] = purchased

something = Groceries()
something.add_item()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "intermediate_python.py", line 14, in <module>
    something = Groceries()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'grocery_list'
```

I tried to resolve this error by removing grocery_list from the def **init** statement (not sure why this would work, I was just playing around) and the error was moved to the next line with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "intermediate_python.py", line 15, in <module>
    something.add_item()
 TypeError: add_item() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'
```

Comment: You need to pass something to `add_item()`... Like something you'd buy at a grocery store.

Comment: I thought I do this with the input statement in add_item, and then when I run something.add_item() I am running that function to pass something into it - obviously this doesn't work, how would you suggest passing something to add_item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialise an instance of your Groceries class you need to provide the parameter "grocery_list" which is defined in your init method

```
class Groceries:
    def __init__(self, grocery_list):
        self.grocery_list = {}
```

Try create your instance using the following:

```
something = Groceries({"milk": 1, "butter": 1})
```

Alternatively, to allow for empty Groceries objects, you can add a default parameter to the init method, you should also be assigning the value of the parameter to the variable self.grocery_list instead of assigning it an empty dictionary:

```
class Groceries:
    def __init__(self, grocery_list={}):
        self.grocery_list = grocery_list
```

and also with your method add_item, again you need to pass a parameter or else removed the parameter (since you're asking for it as input)

```
def add_item(self):
    item = input("name: ")
    purchased = input("amount: ")
    self.grocery_list[item] = purchased


something = Groceries({"milk": 0})
something.add_item()
>> name:
>>> milk
>> amount:
>>> 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I don't quite understand what you mean by "need to pass a parameter or else removed the parameter". The only difference I see in your code is switching the input from False to amount, but I would like to keep the purchased input as False - I will change this to True later in my program if the purchase is bought. I would like to not have to hard code the items into the code and to get the items from the user.

Comment: "you should also be assigning the value of the parameter to the variable self.grocery_list instead of assigning it an empty dictionary" - wouldn't self.grocery_list = {} be a streamlined version of what you suggest?

Comment: If your init method contains the lines self.grocery_list = {}, the variable self.grocery_list will always contain just an empty dictionary. This defeats the purpose of allowing the objects to be created with a list of grocerys at initialization time. Hence, writing self.grocery_list = grocery_list, you will instantiate the class with the values that are passed when you enter something = Groceries({"milk": True}) or something = Groceries({"butter": True}). This will be 2 different grocery lists - one containing just milk and the other containing just butter.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self, grocery_list):
self.grocery_list = {}
```

Although you are passing a grocery_list to your constructor, you are not actually using it to set the value. You merely need to set self.grocery_list equal to the passed argument grocery_list to fix this as I do below.

```
def add_item(self, item):
item = input("name: ")
```

You are also trying to both pass item as an argument and input it manually in the function. This means that regardless of what input you send to add_item, you will always override that value with user input. You can fix this by making the item argument optional and checking if it was passed before prompting the user for input as I do below.

```
purchased = input(False)
self.grocery_list[item] = purchased
```

Also, it is unclear here why you are fetching input with an implicit conversion of the boolean value False to string as a second prompt after asking for the item name. It seems that you want to set some purchased value to True or False, but it is also unclear then why you are using a dictionary for making a list of groceries in the first place unless you intend to include the quantity as the dictionary value. If you just wanted to see if an item was on the grocery list you could use the set() type instead of dict(). This might serve as an example to help you move forward if you want to maintain quantities.

```
class Groceries:
    def __init__(self, grocery_list={}):
        self.grocery_list = grocery_list

    def add_item(self, item='', qty=1):
        if not item: item = input('name: ')
        if item in self.grocery_list:
            self.grocery_list[item] += qty
        else:
            self.grocery_list[item]  = qty

    def item_qty(self, item=''):
        if not item: item = input('name: ')
        return(self.grocery_list[item])

    def print_all(self):
        for key, val in self.grocery_list.items():
            print(val, key)

something = Groceries()
something.add_item('apple')         # add one apple to groceries
print(something.item_qty('apple'))
something.add_item('apple', 3)      # add three apples to groceries
print(something.item_qty('apple'))
something.add_item()                # add arbitrary item to groceries
something.print_all()               # print all groceries
```

Comment: The reason for the boolean value and the dictionary choice is specific to the exercise I am working on - I will later make a function that changes the value from False to True when the item is 'purchased'. I did not want to start on that part of the program until I was comfortable with the initial functions working - I didn't think that part was relevant to the question I was asking so I did not provide more information about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an instance of the Groceries class (`something = Groceries(*args)`), at the end of the initialization, the `Groceries.__init__()` function gets called with the same argument list `*args`.

That means, when you write `something = Groceries()`, you are trying to call the `__init__` function without arguments. On the other hand, the function has a required positional argument `grocery_list` (any positional argument is required if you didn't provide a default for it).

Since your code defines the `grocery_list` as an empty dictionary anyway, you don't need to have this an argument to your `__init__` function, you can simply use:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.grocery_list = {}
```

Which will fix the error.

Or you can have a default value and use:

```
def __init__(self, grocery_list={}):
    self.grocery_list = grocery_list
```

Which would let you use `__init__` without providing the `grocery_list` argument, and using {} in that case.

The exact same case holds for the `add_item` function: you are defining it with a required positional argument, and then you are trying to call it without any argument. Since you aren't passing any value to the function on the function call that you would later use, you can again remove the argument and simply use:

```
def add_item(self):
```